# VBA IE to click on inside a table

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, htmlelements, ihtmldocument2

I need to click `('href' )` on the called 'WS557568037 / Personal Workspace' butnothing has worked. I have tried this code:

```
'Dim htmlElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement  For Each htmlElement In HTML.getElementsByClassName("hoverLink")'Debug.Print htmlElement.getAttribute("href") 
htmlElement.Click  Next htmlElement

Dim evt As Object, evt1 As Object Set evt = HTML.createEvent("HTMLEvents") 
evt.initEvent "mouseover", True, False IE.Document.querySelector(".hoverLink").dispatchEvent evt IE.Document.querySelector(".hoverLink").Focus  IE.Document.querySelector(".hoverLink").click
```

HTML

```
<div class="tableBody" _tbid="_ygf1bc" style="height: 69px;">
<table class="tableBody" id="_ygf1bc" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tbody><tr class="AWTColAlignRow"><td width="1px" style="padding-right: 18px;"></td><td width="" style="padding-right: 27px;"></td><td width="" style="padding-right: 38px;"></td><td width="" style="padding-right: 56px;"></td><td width="" style="padding-right: 50px;"></td><td class="spacer"></td></tr><tr class=" firstRow tableRow1" id="_igbn9d" dr="1" _awtisprimaryrow="1">
<td align="center" class="a-portlet-icon-cell tableBody w-tbl-cell">
<div class="w-doc-portlet-status-hide"></div>
<a id="_a$7voc" href="#" bh="HL" _sf="false"><span class="a-doc-icon-portlet">
<span data-icon="" class="w-icon-default" aria-hidden="true" role="img"></span>

</span>
</a>
</td>


<tr class=" tableRow1" id="_hm6qw" dr="1" _awtisprimaryrow="1">
<td align="center" class="a-portlet-icon-cell tableBody w-tbl-cell">
<div class="w-doc-portlet-status-hide"></div>
<a id="_ayuojd" href="#" bh="HL" _sf="false"><span class="a-doc-icon-portlet">
<span data-icon="" class="w-img" aria-hidden="true" role="img"></span>

</span>
</a>
</td>
<td class="tableBody w-tbl-cell">
<a id="_x2w3t" href="#" bh="HL" _sf="false">WS557568037</a></td>
<td class="tableBody w-tbl-cell">

<a id="_moz9p" href="#" bh="HL" _sf="false" class="hoverLink">Personal Workspace</a>

</td>
<td class="noWrap tableBody w-tbl-cell">

12/18/2020
</td>
<td class="noWrap tableBody w-tbl-cell">

<span class="">Active</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: Dim evt As Object, evt1 As Object
Set evt = HTML.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "mouseover", True, False
IE.Document.querySelector(".hoverLink").dispatchEvent evt    IE.Document.querySelector(".hoverLink").Focus
IE.Document.querySelector(".hoverLink").FireEvent "onClick" IE.Document.querySelector(".hoverLink").click

Comment: I tried using the below code also   

Dim htmlElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    For Each htmlElement In HTML.getElementsByClassName("hoverLink")
        Debug.Print htmlElement.getAttribute("href")
        htmlElement.Click
    Next htmlElement 

I have already tried everything and nothing worked

Comment: Please use [edit] to add your formatted (properly indented code) to your question. Is this a public url or private?

Answer (score 0):

I try to check your HTML code and found that `WS557568037` and `Personal Workspace` are 2 different links and both anchor element contains the `ID` attribute.

We can directly refer to the link by using its `ID` attribute.

Sample VBA code:

```
Sub demo()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim lnk, lnk1 As HTMLAnchorElement
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://Your_Website_URL_here..."  'Modify the URL here...

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
        
    Set lnk = ie.document.querySelector("a[id='_moz9p']")
    lnk.Click
    
    Set lnk1 = ie.document.querySelector("a[id='_x2w3t']")
    lnk1.Click
    'ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code example as per your own requirements.